# Change the line selected in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I'm using jquery to display the line beside the textarea.
from this link:
http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm

Is there any way to change the selected line, so every time the user goes to the next line the line selected changes to the current line.

```
$(function() 
{
    // Target all classed with ".lined"
    $(".lined").linedtextarea(
    {
        //change it from 1 to the current line that the user on.
        selectedLine: 1
    });

    // Target a single one
    $("#mytextarea").linedtextarea();

});
```

Comment: Anyone have an idea about it

Answer (score 0):

yep,

```
function selectLine(n) {
    if (n<1) return false; //If the total number of lines is known it is worth checking you are not above it either
    $(".codelines .lineno.lineselect").removeClass("lineselect")
    $(".codelines .lineno").eq(n-1).addClass("lineselect");
}
```

with a lot of jQuery plugins (when they are full on jQuery widgets) you can use the "options" method to do this kind of thing, like `$(".lined").linedtextarea("options",{selectedLine: 6})` but it doesn't look like this has been turned into a widget. This solution is kind of reverse engineered from the fact that the mod uses the lineselect class to control which line number is highlighted.

We do some checking to make sure we will use a sane value, remove the highlight class from any lines that have it already, and add it to the n-1th line number div (-1 because eq is Zero based).

This won't work if you have multiple lined text boxes on the one page. If that's the case we need to add another parameter to define which one to target and some logic to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for you replay.. how can I apply it, instead of the writing the line... here is a working demo(http://jsfiddle.net/S2yn3/7/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand properly. That fiddle does not use linedtextarea?

Comment: But I can see you already have a function to find the location of a caret, and you are finding the line number from that by splitting on "/n". If I were you I would define that as a function (getLineNumber maybe) and then set up some event handlers at the places where the line could logically change (click, keyup...) to run the function I had in my answer, with it's parameter supplied from your function for getting the line number. eg `$("#test").click(selectLine(parseInt(getLineNumber())));`